# Unable to install lme4 R package in Windows 10

Tags: r, installation, lme4

I am trying to install `lme4` with `R studio` on `Windows 10`, unsuccessfully. Apparently the `nloptr` package is not correctly installed. R returns the following error message:

```
>Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
```

then

```
>ERROR: dependency 'nloptr' is not available for package 'lme4'
```

and at the end

```
>Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
```

When I started to use R studio in Windows I have followed this https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and installed the Rtools, MikTex and InnoSetup.

If I try to install separately the package nloptr it does not work either and gives the same warning message.

Has this happened to anyone while installing `lme4`?

Comment: It would apprear that both packages are available for Windows... what version of R are you using?

Comment: You also downloaded the `.zip` file from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/index.html and installed it with RStudio -> Install -< Install from `Package Archive File`? And the same with the `lme4` package?

Comment: i faced the problem as well. Have you used another Cran Mirror than the rstudio.com ones? That solved the problem for me

Comment: I could install them in this way. Why should not the install.packages() command work?